# Can I assign a set to another set which is being returned by a function

Tags: c++, string, set, syntax-error

```
set<string> getSubstring(string input, string output){
    set<string> m;
    if(input.length() == 0){
        m.insert(output);
        return m;
    }
    
    getSubstring(input.substr(1), output);
    getSubstring(input.substr(1), output + input[0]);
}

int main()
{
   string input;
   cin>>input;
   set<string> a = getSubstring(input, "");
}
```

I wanted to assign the set returned by above function to another set.
What is the right way to do this.
Below statement is causing error.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings and it will tell you that you do not return anything from function that should return `std::set<std::string>`

Comment: Shouldn't you be returning the recursive call `getSubstring`?

Comment: You can see an example of what @Yksisarvinen tells you [here](https://godbolt.org/z/befMjr99q)

Comment: when asking about an error you should include the error message in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what the comments are saying, you'll want to make sure to return the set at the end of the function:

```
set<string> getSubstring(string input, string output){
    set<string> m;
    if(input.length() == 0){
        m.insert(output);
        return m;
    }
    
    getSubstring(input.substr(1), output);
    getSubstring(input.substr(1), output + input[0]);

    // return the set after the recursive calls
    return m;
}
```